# javascript mousemove event in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fullscreen

For some reason, in chrome on PC (not happening on mac), when you enter full screen, the little built in chrome div pops up saying you are now in fullscreen mode and when that div dissapears, it fires a `mousemove` event. Any idea why?

```
var idleTimer;
$videoContainer.mousemove(function()
{
    if (!$jsplayer.prop('paused'))
    {
        if (idleTimer)
        {
            clearTimeout(idleTimer);
            $videoControls.stop(true,true).animate({opacity:1}, animationDuration);
        }
        idleTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $videoControls.stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0}, animationDuration);
        },3000);
    }
});
```

It is basically causing my idle mouse function to fire when the mouse isn't actually moving. This seems to only be happening in chrome. Firefox on the PC doesn't do it, chrome on the mac doesn't do it. I am using `google chrome 30.0.1599.69 m`

**SOLUTION**

```
var idleTimer;
var prevX;
$videoContainer.mousemove(function(e)
{
    if (!$jsplayer.prop('paused'))
    {
        if (idleTimer)
        {
            clearTimeout(idleTimer);
            if (prevX != e.clientX) $videoControls.stop(true,true).animate({opacity:1});
        }
        prevX = e.clientX;
        idleTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            if (!$jsplayer.prop('paused')) $videoControls.stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0}, animationDuration);
        },3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Weird. I am on `30.0.1599.69 m` too and I get `mousemove` events every second even if I am not moving the mouse. http://jsfiddle.net/vnJZe/

Comment: Hmm, mine only fires when the mouse moves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

*(note: I use a global var **window**, remember change it with your global var!)*

```
window.prev_x = null;
function mousemover(e) {
    if ((window.prev_x != null) && (window.prev_x != e.x)) {
        alert(e.x + ' - '+ window.prev_x);
    }
    window.prev_x = e.x;
};
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemover, false);
```

To avoid this event, i guess that **event fire** when the mouse change this window and then return to **DOM of Chrome.**

Comment: Thanks for the idea. While I wasn't able to use `event.x`, I found `event.clientX`, modified my function and confirmed it works across all browsers